build.triggeredby.definitionId not working in Azure DevOps Server 20222
We are triggering few builds as part of our night build from one parent build. We have one build A which is has 30+ "Build Trigger" Tasks to trigger another builds.
All child builds have task to push packages to Octopus. What we are trying not to run the Octopus task in case if build is triggered by Build Definition A.
I try to use build.triggeredby.definitionId in child build to check and add condition in child build B to stop running Octopus Task.
Issue I am having is build.triggeredby.definitionId not returning any value. Tried to write host in powershell step in child build as well.
Any idea why it is not working or any other suggestion.

What Trigger task are you using to trigger the other builds, I suspect it's a marketplace task. That's not how the triggeredBy field works. There is a special trigger that will run a pipeline, when another pipeline finishes, that's when this thing gets filled in. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/pipeline-triggers-classic?view=azure-devops - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers

Hi Sunil, did you have the time to take a look at the answer below?

Using Build.Reason variable
If you don't need to know which exact build triggered the build try using a condition using the Build.Reason variable:
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'ResourceTrigger'))

Build.Reason=ResourceTrigger means the build was triggered by a resource trigger or it was triggered by another build.
Using pipeline parameters
Considering you're not using pipeline resource triggers, and in case you need to know exactly which build triggered the child build try adding a parameter to the child pipeline that will be set by the parent pipeline with the information you need.
Parent pipeline (source):
steps:
  # ...

  - script: >-
      az pipelines run
      --name 'triggered'
      --org $(System.CollectionUri)
      --project $(System.TeamProject)
      --branch $(Build.SourceBranch)
      --parameters "triggeredBy=$(Build.DefinitionName)"
    displayName: 'Queue pipeline'
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

Child pipeline (triggered):
parameters:
  - name: triggeredBy
    type: string
    default: 'dummy'

steps:
  # ...

  - script: |
      echo "Build reason: $(Build.Reason)"
      echo "Triggered by: ${{ parameters.triggeredBy }}"
    displayName: 'Display trigger information'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ lower(parameters.triggeredBy) }}', 'source'))

